# error while trying to alter a column in a table

Tags: sql, ide, derby, alter-table

I am trying to alter the size of a column 'Login' which is a primary key in my table 'Utilisateurs' which is in my in 'ME' database. I tried this command:

```sql
ALTER TABLE ME.UTILISATEURS 
ALTER COLUMN login VARCHAR (50)   ;
```

but I get this error:

> Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: syntax Erreur  : Encountered "varchar" at line 2, column 21.

I am using netbeans IDE, the Derby Driver.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly correct except this one mistake - space between data type and the size. So, the answer would be, ALTER TABLE ME.UTILISATEURS ALTER COLUMN login VARCHAR(50);

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE ME.UTILISATEURS 
ALTER COLUMN login SET DATA TYPE VARCHAR(50)
```